# How to convert curl command to http request?

Tags: rest, google-chrome, http, curl

What would be the equivalent of the next curl command if I use Chrome REST client (HTTP request)?

```
curl --header 'Expect: ' -F username=bob -F password=secret -F file=@'image.jpg' http://api.service.me/api/file
```

I've already found that URL would be `http://api.service.me/api/file`. But I don't know how to parse `-F username=bob -F password=secret -F file=@'image.jpg'` params.

Also I send image in base64 format.

Comment: Chrome REST client = Advanced REST client?

Comment: Yes, I use this client.

Comment: Are you able to find the answer ?

Answer (score -5):

As you can see from [the  `curl` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl), `-F` is explained as

> This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC2388.

There is [a ton of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multipart%2Fform-data) about this special request body encoding.